# Access email client from a web app for iPhone/Blackberry

Tags: iphone, blackberry, iphone-web-app, blackberry-widgets

Can we access the native email client from an iPhone web app, or a BlackBerry web app?

Comment: This is two distinct questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="mailto:example@example.com">Send me Email</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Brad, I've tried it with my iPhone web app and it does work.